# Use of the underscore on service declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Could someone please explain me how the underscore really functions (or means) in the following expression:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>( _ => Configuration );
```

I have read some articles, but I cannot fully understand.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It is being used as a parameter for the expression. it is the same as `services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>( p => Configuration );` or any other valid name given to an expression parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some developers simply use this special variable name in order to say: I need to supply a parameter name here but the implementation of my Func doesn't use it. That's all. You could as well use any other name.